# Paramterized Testing with Junit

Tags: junit4, parameterized-unit-test

How can I test the following method with parameterized testing in JUnit

```
public class Math {
    public static int add(int a, int b) {  
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

I wish to know how parameterized testing with Junit will be implemented to test this method, when I want to test it with 10 different args.

Answer (score 5):

The test class must have an annotation `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` and function returning a `Collection<Object[]>` should be marked with `@Parameters` and a constructor accepting the inputs and the expected output(s)

API: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html

```
 @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
 public class AddTest {
        @Parameters
        public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
                return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                                { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 ,2}, 
                                  { 2, 1, 3 }, { 3, 2, 5 }, 
                                  { 4, 3, 7 }, { 5, 5, 10 },
                                  { 6, 8, 14 } } });
        }

        private int input1;
        private int input2;

        private int sum;

        public AddTest(int input1, int input2, int sum) {
                this.input1= input1;
                this.input2= input2;
                this.sum = sum;
        }

        @Test
        public void test() {

                assertEquals(sum, Math.Add(input1,input2));
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

recently i started [zohhak](http://zohhak.googlecode.com) project. i believe it's much cleaner than @Parametrized:

```
@TestWith({
   "25 USD, 7",
   "38 GBP, 2",
   "null, 0"
})
public void testMethod(Money money, int anotherParameter) {
   ...
}
```